# Java Game actionPerformed questions

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

Hi everyone so recently i've made a game similar to doodle jump with a jumper/object jumping to the next platform on top and if you fall of you lose. So anyway my game all works but there is one problem, I've make it that if you press on the space bar the jumper/object jumps up, ok here is the problem: if you keep holding on the space bar then the jumper will keep moving up until I let go of the space bar, how do you make it that when you press or hold on the space bar the jumper/object only jumps ones rather then keeps going up until i let go of the space bar?

Here's what's going on in my code:

Here is my action performed class where the jumper jumps up or down

```
static boolean gameplay=false;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (gameplay==true){
        if (jumper==true){
            DoodleHeight+20;
        }
        if (jumper==false){
            DoodleHeight=DoodleHeight-10;
        }
```

Here I have the keys that controls the jumps

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        jumper=true;
    }   
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        jumper=false;
    }
}
```

how would you fix the problem? I need help and i can't figure it out.

here is my code with the flag:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;
public class DoodleJumpp extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
static JFrame f;
static int width=1200, height=930;
static int DoodleW=500, DoodleH=500;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth=200, DoodlePlatformHeight=400;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth1=400, DoodlePlatformHeight1=530;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth2=900, DoodlePlatformHeight2=874;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth3=345, DoodlePlatformHeight3=643;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth4=711, DoodlePlatformHeight4=957;
static boolean rightjumper,leftjumper;
static boolean jumper;
static boolean test=true;
static boolean gameplay=true;
public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(DoodlePlatformWidth, DoodlePlatformHeight,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth1, DoodlePlatformHeight1,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth2, DoodlePlatformHeight2,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth3, DoodlePlatformHeight3,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth4, DoodlePlatformHeight4,200,30);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(DoodleW, DoodleH,50,50);
}
public static void main(String a[]){
    DoodleJumpp D = new DoodleJumpp();
    f = new JFrame();
    D.init();
    f.add(D);
    f.setSize(width,height);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.repaint();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Timer t=new Timer(10,D);
    t.start();
}
public void init (){
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (gameplay==true){
        if (jumper==true&&test==false){
            DoodlePlatformHeight=DoodlePlatformHeight+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight1=DoodlePlatformHeight1+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight2=DoodlePlatformHeight2+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight3=DoodlePlatformHeight3+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight4=DoodlePlatformHeight4+20;
        }
        if (jumper==false&&test==false){
            DoodlePlatformHeight=DoodlePlatformHeight-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight1=DoodlePlatformHeight1-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight2=DoodlePlatformHeight2-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight3=DoodlePlatformHeight3-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight4=DoodlePlatformHeight4-10;
        }
        if (leftjumper==true&&test==false){
            DoodleW=(DoodleW-15);
        }
        if (rightjumper==true&&test==false){
            DoodleW=(DoodleW+15);
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight1>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth1=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight1=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight2>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth2=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight2=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight3>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth3=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight3=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight4>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth4=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight4=0;
        }
        if (DoodleH==DoodlePlatformHeight-50 && DoodleW>=DoodlePlatformWidth-30  && DoodleW<=DoodlePlatformWidth+180){
            test=true;
        }
        if (DoodleH==DoodlePlatformHeight1-50 && DoodleW>=DoodlePlatformWidth1-30  && DoodleW<=DoodlePlatformWidth1+180){
            test=true;
        }
        if (DoodleH==DoodlePlatformHeight2-50 && DoodleW>=DoodlePlatformWidth2-30  && DoodleW<=DoodlePlatformWidth2+180){
            test=true;
        }
        if (DoodleH==DoodlePlatformHeight3-50 && DoodleW>=DoodlePlatformWidth3-30  && DoodleW<=DoodlePlatformWidth3+180){
            test=true;
        }
        if (DoodleH==DoodlePlatformHeight4-50 && DoodleW>=DoodlePlatformWidth4-30  && DoodleW<=DoodlePlatformWidth4+180){
            test=true;
        }
        f.repaint();
    }
}
static boolean flag=true;
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && flag == true){
        flag = false;
        jumper=true;
        test=false;
    }  
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        leftjumper=true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
        rightjumper=true;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        flag = true;
        jumper=false;

    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        leftjumper=false;

    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
        rightjumper=false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A key is pressed multiple times or it is kept pressed (both are same scenario). So in your case the program gets the same input and  it does `DoodleHeight+20;` and the jumper will keep moving up until you let go of the space bar**

Comment: ok but how can i change the code to make it only jump ones rather then keeps jumping up?

Comment: ok thanks anyways i'll try to think of it myself

Comment: @jackzhang so if you level has 30 platforms you are going to have 30 variables and conditions ? you need to keep on the currentHeight of the platform that he is standing on and update that when he jumps and lands on another platform

Comment: sure i'll think about it

Comment: @jackzhang also see my answer I can provide you with some code if you understand the main idea

Comment: ok sure thanks, and i do get the main idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are bringing down the character only when the key is released !

Specifically with this logic:

```
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        jumper=false;
    }
}
```

And then with this logic when actionPerformed

```
    if (jumper==false){
        DoodleHeight=DoodleHeight-10;
    }
```

You need something similar to gravity that after a few time lapse brings down the character to the ground level

One way to do this is to use a `TimerTask` that starts as soon as the character jumps and the task on every timer tick reduces the height of the character until is 0 or the same as before it jumped.

Comment: That's what he's doing right? He has a loop, the first bit of code. And if the jumper is true then he goes up else he goes down. The events just change the jumper flag.

Comment: The OP needs some way to ignore the fact that the `jumper` variable is been set true through repeated key strokes while the space bar is been held (so the `keyPressed` method will be called alot of times in quick succession)

Comment: @MadProgrammer not only that, after the character has jumped even if no action/touch happen he needs to start bringing down the character that is the reason for using a TimerTask

Comment: But has already been stated, they are doing what you've suggested

Comment: @MadProgrammer maybe this answer deserves an upvote ?

Comment: Thanks man I am looking into the TimerTask that you said, but the thing is that the jumper is not really the object that is jumping up to down, I made it that the jumper is stationary while it can only move left or right,  the platforms on the other hand are the ones that are being moved up or down when the space bar is pressed. How do set the ground level for the jumper when it isn't even moving up or down?? By the way I put the platforms in a loop, which means when the platform touches the bottom of the JFrame it will rest set it's hight to the top of the JFrame as it falls down again.

Comment: @jackzhang well I will not call it jumperHeight it would be something like currentPlataform it could be the index to a platform collection that has the heights or it could be currentPlatformHeight which is the actual height (in fact is the vertical scroll of your platforms) Feel free to post another question and link it here to help you

Answer (score 1):

Well you could share a boolean variable between you `keyReleased` and `keyPressed` code. When the key is pressed set the value to false and then add that as a condition to your `keyPressed` code so that when the flag is false it won't do anything. Similar in you `keyReleased` code set the flag to true again so the `keyPressed` code works again.

So with these modifications your code becomens:

```
static boolean flag = true;//<- your flag
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && flag == true){//<- only jump if the flag is true
        flag = false;//<-- set flag to false, this will be reset by the keyReleased code again
        jumper=true;
    }   
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        flag = true;//<-- reset flag to be able to jump again
        jumper=false;
    }
}
```

I hope this help :)

EDIT #1

Version 2 this works altough you probably want to reset the flag when you land on the platform otherwise the user can just spam the space bar.

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && flag == true){
    flag = false;
    jumper=true;
    test=false;
}else{
    jumper=false;
}
if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
    leftjumper=true;
}
if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
    rightjumper=true;
}
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    flag = true;
    jumper=false;

}
if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
    leftjumper=false;

}
if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
    rightjumper=false;
}
}
```